# if statement always returning false on string comparison

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-edittext

> I have used this code to try and confirm that the user input
>   passwords are the same and there is no mismatch, before proceeding to
>   the next activity. But the if statement always returns a false. It works fine for hardcoded text, but always returns a false for if. Am I missing something?

```
private void validate(EditText userPassword, EditText userConfirmPassword){
   String userPasswordtext = userPassword.getEditableText().toString();
  String userConfirmPasswordtext = userConfirmPassword.getEditableText().toString();

    if(userPasswordtext == userConfirmPasswordtext){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Toast a=Toast.makeText(this, "Passwords do not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        a.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .equals when comparing two strings

```java
if (userPasswordtext.equals(userConfirmPasswordtext)) {
```